# SVG images not rendering in Safari

Tags: html, css, svg, safari, svg-filters

```
<svg id="button-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 40 40" xml:space="preserve">
        <defs>
          <pattern id="pattern1" height="100%" width="100%">
            <filter id="shadow">
              <feDropShadow dx="0" dy="0" stdDeviation="2.2" />
            </filter>
            <rect height="100%" width="100%" fill=${backgroundColor}></rect>
            <image id="image" xlink:href=${backgroundImage}></image>
          </pattern>
        </defs> 
        <circle id="circle" cx="20" cy="20" r="20" filter="url(#shadow)"  fill="url(#pattern1)"/>
      </svg>
```

I have tried multiple solutions from stackoverflow but none seem to work. Can anybody please help me on this?

Note: both filter and the fill color are showing. It’s only the image that’s missing.

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/svg-safari-image-t9ng3?file=/src/index.js

Edit: Thank's to Robert Longson's answer I found out that you need to set the height and width explicitly in the image tags 'height/width' attribute for the image to show in Safari. Now I have another problem if the height/width is supposed to be 'auto', removing the attribute from the image tag works in Chrome but the image again disappears in Safari. Is there any fix for this?

Comment: Try this online [checker](https://validator.w3.org/) to help identify issues.

Comment: @RobertLongson the height and width is defined via style.

Comment: @rtx13 tried doing that. It gave me `Namespace prefix xlink for href on image is not defined`. But its still not working even after I provided the namespace.

Comment: It works for me in Safari. I see an image in the codesandbox.

Comment: Yes I added the width and the height as an attribute and it started working. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Safari needs the image to have height and width values.

Using the image's native width and height i.e. a default value of auto is a [change in the new SVG 2 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/embedded.html#ImageElement). Firefox and Chrome have implemented this and I imagine Safari will too at some point.

Comment: Is there anyway I can set the native height/width to `auto`?

Comment: So if the height/width is auto it will not work in Safari at the moment?

Comment: This did the trick for me! SVG worked on all browsers except Safari without width and height. As soon as I added width and height attributes to the SVG then it rendered in Safari as well.

Comment: I was able to get it to work by only adding the 'width' attr.